# How many front end servers?

Tags: 2013, central-administration, front-end

What are the possibilities to know how many WFE servers there are in a SharePoint 2013 farm? 
Is it only possible through the Central Admin, and how can I see this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute the below PowerShell command and get a list of all the servers with their roles

```
Write-Host "Servers and their Roles in the farm:"
Get-SPServer  | select name, role
```

[Source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607694(v=office.14).aspx)